# Differences between Linux and Hadoop file system

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

What are the differences between a Linux and a Hadoop file sytem? I knew few of them, just wanted to know more details.

Answer (score 1):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811959/hdfs-vs-lfs-how-hadoop-dist-file-system-is-built-over-local-file-system) similar question.

First of all you cannot compare Linux file system with HDFS, But 
upto my knowledge,

1. HDFS - Name itself says that its a distributed file system where the data stores into several blocks on different clusters.
2. HDFS write once read many but Local file system write many, ready many
3. Local file system is a default storage architecture comes with OS but HDFS is a file system for hadoop framework refer here [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html).
4. HDFS is an another layer for Local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below links to see the difference :

[Linux File System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained)

[Hadoop File System](http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_illuminated/HDFS_Intro.html)