# What does it mean by 'local file system?'

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I'm currently reading about hadoop and I  came across this which has puzzled me (please bear in mind that I am a complete novice when it comes to hadoop) -

Use the Hadoop get command to copy a file from HDFS to your local file
system:

```
$ hadoop hdfs dfs -get file_name /user/login_user_name
```

What is a local file system?  I understand that a HDFS partitions a file into different blocks throughout the cluster (but I know there's more to it than that). My understanding of the above command is that I can copy a file from the cluster to my personal (i.e. local) computer? Or is that completely wrong? I'm just not entirely sure what is meant by a local file system.

Answer (score 0):

LocalFS means it may be your LinuxFS or WindowsFS. And which is not part of the DFS.

Your understanding is correct, using `-get` you are getting file from HDFS to Local FS and you cannot use both `hadoop` and `hdfs`. Command should be like below

`hdfs dfs -get file_name local_path` or `hadoop fs -get file_name local_path`

Answer (score 0):

As per the file system logic, you can divide the filesystem into different drives. in the same way, you can create hadoop file system as a separate filesystem in linux file system.
Your local file system would be the File system over which you have installed the hadoop.your machine act as local in this case when copying file from your machine to the hadoop.
you might want to look at :[HDFS vs LFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811959/hdfs-vs-lfs-how-hadoop-dist-file-system-is-built-over-local-file-system)

Answer (score -1):

THINK of a cluster node (server) as having to fulfill 2 needs:

1. the need to store its own operating system, application and user data-related files; and
2. the need to store its portion of sharded or "distributed" cluster data files.

In each cluster data node then there needs to be 2 independent file systems:

1. the LOCAL ("non-distributed") file system:

   - stores the OS and all OS-related ancillary ("helper") files;
   - stores the binary files which form the applications which run on the server;
   - stores additional data files, but these exist as simple files which are NOT sharded/replicated/distributed in the server's "cluster data" disks;
   - typically comprised of numerous partitions - entire formatted portions of a single disk or multiple disks;
   - typically also running LVM in order to ensure "expandability" of these partitions containing critical OS-related code which cannot be permitted to saturate or the server will suffer catastrophic (unrecoverable) failure.

AND

2. the DISTRIBUTED file system:

   - stores only the sharded, replicated portions of what are actually massive data files "distributed" across all the other data drives of all the other data nodes in the cluster
   - typically comprised of at least 3 identical disks, all "raw" - unformatted, with NO RAID of any kind and NO LVM of any kind, because the cluster software (installed on the "local" file system) is actually responsible for its OWN replication and fault-tolerance, so that RAID and LVM would actually be REDUNDANT, and therefore cause unwanted LATENCY in the entire cluster performance.

LOCAL <==> OS and application and data and user-related files specific or "local" to the specific server's operation itself;

DISTRIBUTED <==> sharded/replicated data; capable of being concurrently processed by all the resources in all the servers in the cluster.

A file can START in a server's LOCAL file system where it is a single little "mortal" file - unsharded, unreplicated, undistributed; if you were to delete this one copy, the file is gone gone GONE...

... but if you first MOVE that file to the cluster's DISTRIBUTED file system, where it becomes sharded, replicated and distributed across at least 3 different drives likely on 3 different servers which all participate in the cluster, so that now if a copy of this file on one of these drives were to be DELETED, the cluster itself would still contain 2 MORE copies of the same file (or shard); and WHERE in the local system your little mortal file could only be processed by the one server and its resources (CPUs + RAM)...

... once that file is moved to the CLUSTER, now it's sharded into myriad smaller pieces across at least 3 different servers (and quite possibly many many more), and that file can have its little shards all processed concurrently by ALL the resources (CPUs & RAM) of ALL the servers participating in the cluster.

And that the difference between the LOCAL file system and the DISTRIBUTED file system operating on each server, and that is the secret to the power of cluster computing :-) !...

Hope this offers a clearer picture of the difference between these two often-confusing concepts!

-Mark from North Aurora